# TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when I try to smooth out a photo

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

In one guide I saw this here is the code:

```
if args['flatten'] > 0:
    image = image.flatten()
    image = image.reshape((1, image.shape))
```

This is executed if the image needs to be smoothed, but I get

```
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape))
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

PS

```
image = cv2.resize(image, (args['width'], args['height']))
image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
```

Comment: You already asked the same question before, please post questions only once. You can always edit your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

That's beacause `image.shape` is a tuple of the form (width, height, channel).
So when you write `image = image.reshape((1, image.shape))`
it's the same as writting  `image = image.reshape((1, (args['width'], args['height']))` if `image.shape = (args['width'], args['height'])`.

But image.reshape need intergers, so either you write :

```
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))
```

or

```
image = image.reshape((1, *image.shape))
```